# No USB devices working in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, hardware-failure, windows-server-2008

Before telling my problem, I need to tell you guys one thing. I searched Google, Superuser and StackOverflow a lot and I can't find anything useful.

I use a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine with Intel i3 processor, 4 GB RAM. Its motherboard is ECS H55H-CM. From yesterday no USB devices are working - keyboard, mouse, pendrives, card readers, printer. Am using PS/2 mouse and keyboard now.

Here is the Device Manager.

[image]

As you see there, the USB controllers (Intel (R) 5 Series/3400 series Chipset family USB Enhanced Host Controller) was mentioned below Huawei Mobile Connect. After an unistall and restart they started to appear under Other Devices.

This is the error when I looked in the properties -
"The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)
This operation requires an interactive window station.
To reinstall the drivers for this device, click Reinstall Driver."

- I tried unplugging and plugging many times.
- Tried to install drivers, and still nothing happens. Device Manager is the same even after installing drivers.
- Uninstalled each USB controller and restarted my system.
- Scanned for hardware changes.

I tried each and everything I saw in many websites and nothing did any good. So what should I do to make the USB devices working ?

---

This is the report by Microsoft FixIt.
[image]

---

Tried SFC.exe/scannow. This is result.
[image]

---

### Update

As a last try I uninstalled both the 'Other Devices'(refer first image) and restarted my system. After restarting 7 Found New Hardware windows appeared I choose 'Ask Me Later'. Then I connected USB Mouse, Pen drive, printer and keyboard. All devices worked except keyboard. So I removed USB keyboard and plugged PS/2 keyboard. Now the Device Manager looks like this -

[image]

If I select to install drivers when the 'Found New Hardware' window appears none of the USB devices work. Now only USB keyboard is not working. I have to choose 'Ask Me Later' option every time I strats my system to make the USB devices work.

How can I solve this issue fully ?

---

### Update

The Hardware ID's of the Unknown Devices are:

1. USB\ROOT_HUB20&VID8086&PID3B34&REV0006
2. USB\ROOT_HUB20&VID8086&PID3B3C&REV0006
3. USB\VID_8087&PID_0020&REV_0000
4. USB\VID_8087&PID_0020&REV_0000

Comment: What is the error shown, if you look at the device properties?

Comment: @BigChris This is the error - "The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)
This operation requires an interactive window station.
To reinstall the drivers for this device, click Reinstall Driver."

Comment: Everything is pointing to the drivers not being installed for the devices... Can you install the Intel Driver Update Utility? Can you paste up the hardware IDs of the missing devices and the drivers/versions of what is supposedly already installed?

Comment: @BigChris Please send a link to download Intel Driver Utility. I already downloaded something like this and installed, but it didn't solved the problem.

Comment: @BigChris Ok. I downloaded Intel Driver Update Utility and scanned my system. It found nothing, no update shown. You can see the hardware ID of the missing devices from the first figure of my question. Also you can understand the other missing devices if you compare your device manager with mine from the first figure.

Comment: The hardware IDs can be found by right clicking the device -> properties -> details tab -> 'Hardware Ids' from dropdown menu.

Comment: @BigChris ID of 3B34 - PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B34&SUBSYS_13241019&REV_06
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B34&SUBSYS_13241019
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B34&CC_0C0320
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B34&CC_0C03
                                                                                                                ,and ID of 3B3C - PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B3C&SUBSYS_13241019&REV_06
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B3C&SUBSYS_13241019
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B3C&CC_0C0320
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3B3C&CC_0C03

Comment: I've just extracted the following .zip and it appears to have an inf file that matches your device ID... it should work with your Server 2008 R2 install: http://asia.dl.sapphiretech.com/archive/gm/drivers/infinst_autol_635137251862408024.zip

Comment: @BigChris "An unknown error occured. The setup will exit now" - This error occured.

Comment: Can you install the driver manually by using "update driver" for the devices? Don't force it it to use the driver - if it doesn't work it'll complain and we'll know it's the wrong driver.

Comment: @BigChris No. "Windows encountered a problem installing driver for your device"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29893/discussion-between-big-chris-and-tomin-jacob).

Comment: @BigChris I tried to install in the Safe Mode, no improvements. The error is- "Windows encountered a problem installing the driver software of your device"

Comment: OK, running out of options here... you may need to contact your motherboard manufacturer and see if they offer drivers for your OS... sorry!

Comment: Are there any Service Packs available for your 2008 R2 install?

Comment: @BigChris No Service Pack updates are there.

Comment: As in they aren't installed or aren't available to install? If they're not installed then it may be worth a shot downloading and installing the latest one for 2008 R2 and see if that makes any difference...?

Comment: @BigChris All the updates were installed

Comment: Try [To Delete the UpperFilters and LowerFilters Registry Values](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/driverssupport/ht/upperfilters-lowerfilters.htm). The latest chipset driver seem to be [this one](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/18180/Intel-5500-5520-3400-Chipset-Driver-for-Windows-) from 2011 (!), which might not fit Win2008 R2. If no go, try these [repair methods](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4162.windows-server-2008-repair-steps-for-no-boot-issues.aspx) for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try To [Delete the UpperFilters and LowerFilters Registry Values](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/driverssupport/ht/upperfilters-lowerfilters.htm),
using regedit to access the subkey for your device at :
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class`.

Try the latest chipset driver for your device, although dating from 2011 (!) it might not fit Windows 2008 R2 (in that case stay with the generic driver furnished by Windows):
[Intel® 5500/5520/3400 Chipset Driver for Windows](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/18180/Intel-5500-5520-3400-Chipset-Driver-for-Windows-).

If nothing works, try these [repair methods for Windows](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4162.windows-server-2008-repair-steps-for-no-boot-issues.aspx) :

- Boot into "repair your computer / Command prompt", cd to
  `X:\sources\recovery` and launch `startrep.exe`.
- Run `chkdsk C: /f` and then `chkdsk c: /r`, just in case
- As last measure, [Perform an In-Place Upgrade](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2255099).

Ensure having good backups before starting.

---

From your last edit, it seems that Windows installs the wrong USB driver for your
motherboard.

[Driver Scape](http://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/ecs/laptops-desktops/h55h-cm/4837) has various drivers that you might try,
especially the ones for System & Chipset,
while continuing with blocking Windows from updating them.
Driver Scape is commercial, but the drivers it lists are free to download from the
manufacturer. You can click on any driver in the list to go into its details,
then google for it with the version number.

For example, searching for "Intel(R) 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Family 2 port Serial ATA Storage Controller 3B26 9.1.9.1006" got me [this website](http://sciologness.com/download/2674/intelr-5-series-3400-series-chipset-family-2-port-serial-ata-storage-controller-3b26.html) where the
driver seems downloadable.
I would verify first each download using [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/).

This is a long search and some of the drivers you will find might not fit your
hardware, since websites like Driver Scape tend to list too many drivers
so as to attract paying customers.

---

You can also find drivers to your devices in Device Manager : Right-click the
device and in its Properties go to the Details tab and use the value of
Hardware Ids to identify the device. For more info see the article :
[How to Find Drivers for Unknown Devices in the Device Manager](http://www.howtogeek.com/193798/how-to-find-drivers-for-unknown-devices-in-the-device-manager/).

[image]

Comment: I found UpperFilters, but not LowerFilters. What to do, clean UpperFilters ?   How to boot into "Repair your computer/CMD" ? I don't get it.

Comment: You need to be sure of the device, since normally both items are available. If only one exists, you might try to delete it, but export it first and create a system restore point, just in case. Boot into "Repair your computer/CMD" requires a boot CD/USB and is explained in [the link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4162.windows-server-2008-repair-steps-for-no-boot-issues.aspx) I gave above - let me know if you need more information than is found there.

Comment: From your last edit, it seems that Windows installs the wrong drivers for your motherboard. [Driver Scape](http://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/ecs/laptops-desktops/h55h-cm/4837) has various drivers for it. You might try them, especially the ones for System & Chipset, while continuing with blocking Windows from updating them.

Comment: It seems that DriverToolkit requires a registration. Am not planning to pay now. So what to do with it ?

Comment: These drivers are free to download from the manufacturer. You can click on a driver in the list to go into its details, then google for it with the version number. For example, searching for "Intel(R) 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Family 2 port Serial ATA Storage Controller 3B26 9.1.9.1006" got me [this website](http://sciologness.com/download/2674/intelr-5-series-3400-series-chipset-family-2-port-serial-ata-storage-controller-3b26.html) where the driver seems downloadable. I would also verify before using each download using [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/).

Comment: This search will take some time, and some of the drivers might not fit your hardware. Websites like Driver Scape  tend to list too many drivers.

Comment: You said "it seems that Windows installs the wrong drivers for your motherboard", and I think this is the reason. I searched a lot, but I can't find the correct drivers yet. Anyway you said the right thing. Edit your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: OK. Is the example driver I found useful and relates to your hardware?

Comment: No, I got error while installing error. But I am sure that somehow my drivers are corrupted. I have to find the right one and install it.

Comment: I added another method of finding drivers thru Hardware Ids.

Comment: I tried that with no luck. Some links were shown, but they are leading to sites containing harmful contents.

Comment: If you add the Hardware Id of your USB to the post, I'll have a go at it.

Comment: Its added, and please note that my system is Windows Server 2008 R2. While I searched using the Hardware ID I was able to find drivers that support other versions of Windows, except mine.

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 is the server variant of Windows 7, so a driver for W7 will do. You might try one of these [free driver update tools](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/driversites/tp/free-driver-updater-tools.htm), but don't update devices that work well. One or two of these should do the work for you.

Comment: Or I have also heard mentioned [Unknown Device Identifier](http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html).

Answer (score 3):

"From yesterday no USB devices are working"

If this happened suddenly the USB controller may have failed.

1. Insert a USB key
2. Reboot the machine and see if the BIOS sees it as a boot device
3. If it does, its a software problem, somethings wrong in windows. If it doesnt, the board is dead, RMA it.

Comment: My keyboard and mouse works until the device starts booting. After that it won't work. While turning the system on the keyboard and mouse blinks.

Comment: To clarify, a USB keyboard works for bios interaction, but stops once the OS begins to load?

Comment: Yes. Both keyboard and mouse stops working when OS starts to load.

Comment: Ok cool, its confirmed as software so. Try SFC.exe /scannow next

Comment: I updated my question and you see the result for SFC.exe/scannow

Comment: You need to pastebin the CBS log. Ive no practice reading them but other SU posters will be able to interpret.

Comment: @Linnef4ult Its very big. It is 300+ lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usbdeview.zip)

Make sure that USB device was appearing over at the connected lists,try to enable it from there ,Apart from that check the following :

Check whether it was disabled at one of the methods listed over [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-enable-usb-windowunlock-pen-drive-at-office-or-school-computer)

also check this Microsoft [Forum](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/817900) ,make a note that if your system is idle for more than 1 hour the USB might not work properly and list out at [device manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/978258)

Comment: How to download USBDeview ? I can't find any link or option to download it there.

Comment: updated link,you could find at the end of the page below the feedback

Answer (score 0):

It may be a long shot, but check your local policy for "Removable Disks:Deny read access".

[image]

Comment: It is all 'Not configured'. What to do now ?

Comment: Again, another long shot, perhaps check to see if your antivirus or endpoint software (if installed) is disabling the ports.

Comment: No, my antivirus is Quick Heal and it is not disabling the ports.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days trying a lot of things. I uninstalled **USBPcap** from From programs and features and now everything works like before.

Answer (score 0):

Or you try an older USB-Hub. This is what I tried and it worked immediately. USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 is not that compatible, as promised. ;-)